# Dudas sobre ciclos de vida y comunicación entre componentes de Angular

Tags: angular, entrada

He leído la documentación de Angular y he buscado en varias fuentes pero aún no me quedan claros estos conceptos.

1. Mi primera duda se basa en lo siguiente. Entiendo que el ciclo de vida `ngOnInit` se ejecuta al cargarse la componente, `ngOninit` se ejecuta cuando se detectan cambios y `ngOnDestroy` para limpiar el componente una vez que se deje de mostrar, pero aún así me quedan dudas. 
   ¿Cualquier función que yo quiera ejecutar inmediatamente al cargarse la componente la tengo que colocar en el `ngOnInit`? ¿Qué tipo de funciones o código se colocaría en `ngOnChanges` y en `ngOnDestroy`? Me cuesta entender esto sin unos ejemplos.
2. Entiendo que los `input` se utilizan para comunicar componentes y pasar datos entre ellos. Según leí es para pasarlos desde un componente padre a un componente hijo, pero, ¿ésto cómo se define? Es decir, ¿cómo sé cuál es el padre y cuál es el hijo? Y, ¿el intercambio puede lograrse en ambas direcciones (padre-hijo e hijo-padre)?

Espero puedan ayudarme a aclarar estas dudas, se los agradecería. ¡Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

El evento `ngOnInit` se ejecuta antes de mostrarse el componente, normalmente se aprovecharía para efectuar llamadas a micros, aprovisionamiento de información a las propiedades bindadas en el template y todo lo que precise el componente para ser mostrado.

El evento `ngOnChange` es para cualquier cambio en los datos del componente, pudiendo escuchar así si un dato input es cambiado y hacer una acción.

El evento `ngOnDestroy`es para efectuar una acción cuando el componente se destruye (deja de mostrarse en pantalla), un ejemplo sería mantener logs de cambio de pantalla o liberación de metadatos para asegurarte que se libera la memoria (normalmente lo hace automáticamente).

En cuanto a los `@Input()` tal y como indicas es para comunicación entre el componente padre e hijo.

El componente padre será el componente que contenga (muestre) en el template al otro componente, un ejemplo app.component.ts sería el componente padre de cualquier otro componente.

Para comunicación bidireccional tendríamos además el decorador [@Output()](https://angular.io/api/core/Output) (sirve para bindar una propiedad del padre que va a ser modificada en el hijo) y el decorador [@Input()](https://angular.io/api/core/Input) (comentado anteriormente).

Ten en cuenta que siempre que bindas una propiedad del padre al hijo, transmites un punto de referencia del sector de memoria siendo posible que una propiedad bindada en un @Input pueda llegar a ser modificada por el componente hijo.